# How do I pass in a variable of the form "Class<HostResolver> hostResolver"

Tags: java

I'm using java to do a logging project, and I've come across a method that wants a parameter of the form `Class<HostResolver> hostResolver`, where HostResolver.class is an interface. Can anyone suggest what I'm meant to be passing in here?

If I pass in HostResolver.class it will accept it as a parameter, but then fail at hostResolver.newInstance(). However if I pass in an implementation of HostResolver it says it's not of the right type for the method.

Here's the specific method.

```
protected static HostResolver createHostResolver(final Class<HostResolver> hostResolver) throws
        IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    return hostResolver.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: That method is declared badly. The parameter type should be `Class<? extends HostResolver>`. Requiring that the parameter *be* a `HostResolver`, when `HostResolver` is an interface, is just plain wrong. If you cannot change the method, you can work around that problem with even worse code: `createHostResolver((Class)MyHostResolver.class)`. The raw `Class` cast will bypass the problem, but it's a *hack!*

Comment: Thanks, it turns out the method was meant to be Class<? extends HostResolver> but that the change hadn't been pushed through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the method was meant to have Class, but that the change hadn't been pushed through. Once this was changed I was able to pass it a class that extends HostResolver

```
protected static HostResolver createHostResolver(final Class<? extends HostResolver> HostResolver) throws
    IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
return hostResolver.newInstance();
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Your issues is that you have specified a specific class in the generic rather than a wildcard. You need to specify a wildcard if you want to pass in an implementation. Then you should be able to pass in the class object for a class that implements `HostResolver`. Because `newInstance` is called that class must have a constructor with no arguments.

Here's an example

```
interface Interface {

}

class Subclass implements Interface {

}

private static Interface makeHost(Class<? extends Interface> hostClass)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return hostClass.newInstance();
}


System.out.println(makeHost(Subclass.class).getClass().getName());
```